# How do you read an Engine Throttling specification of 3-5:1 in percent thrust load?

Tags: engines, restartable-engine

I was looking at the CECE engine by Aerojet, however I am not sure how to determine the trust range of percent thrust range of the engine. How I can translate the throttling spec into a percent load range for the rocket engine?

Answer (score 3):

This is an engine still in development, so I believe that means the throttle range varies with the test configuration, from 3:1 (i.e. if maximum throttle is 100% thrust, minimum is 33% thrust) to 5:1 (20%-100%).